# Angular 8 - Sorting a recursive tree component by type of value

Tags: angular, typescript

Given the following object:

```js
const data = {
    "root": {
         "title": "Shapes",
         "shapes": { ... },
         "description": "All sorts of geometrical whizz"
    }
}
```

I'd need to find a way to sort this object to have the keys with objects appear above the keys with strings, such as below:

```js
const data = {
    "root": {
         "shapes": { ... },
         "title": "Shapes",
         "description": "All sorts of geometrical whizz"
    }
}
```

What I have tried was the `sort()` function:

```js
const sorted = Object.values(root).sort((v) => typeof v === 'object' ? -1 : 1)
```

While this works to sort the *values* while keeping the root object pristine, the keys are lost in this new `sorted` array...

```js
[
    {...}, 
    "Shapes", 
    "All sorts of geometrical whizz"
]
```

...while it must be kept as an object as the keys are used by a recursive Tree Component, where sorting like this is moot:

```html
<ng-template *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(data)">
    <div *ngIf="typeof key === 'object'>
        <button (click)="show(value)">
            {{key}} 
        </button>
        <this-template [data]="data[key]">
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="typeof key === 'string'>
        <button (click)="show(value)">
            {{key}} 
        </button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

as the component will still render based on the structure of `root`:

```
↓ root
    |- title
    |- > shapes
    |- description
```

while the desired structure is this:

```
↓ root
    |- > shapes
    |- title
    |- description
```

Thus, to define the problem in a single question;

How would I be able to sort an object by the **type** of the key's value, in order to render a recursive component to display items with objects before items with strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Object.entries` and a reduce you should be able to achieve the desired result:

```js
const data = {
  "root": {
    "shapes": { /* ... */ },
    "title": "Shapes",
    "description": "All sorts of geometrical whizz"
  }
}

const sorted = Object.entries(data.root)
  .sort(([key, v]) => typeof v === 'object' ? -1 : 1)
  .reduce((newObj, [key, v]) => ({ ...newObj, [key]: v }), {})
  
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: This will also change the string properties order.  I think you should return '0' instead '1' in your sort

Comment: It does change the order of strings to descending order when using `1`, but changing it to `0` somehow makes the sorting ineffective. The same effect occurs when replacing `-1` with `0` and shuffling about. That being said, I did try to chain the sort with a reduce but have struggled with creating the keys in the resulting `newObj` object, Teddy Sterne 's example fits as the final piece to the puzzle. The `.reduce()` function is very powerful, but does need some training to use!

Comment: To further elaborate on the string order, it appears that running the semi-oneliner in the application (typescript) with `? -1 : 1` does sort the strings in descending order (last to first - top to bottom) but in a node REPL the order is unchanged. interesting!

Answer (score 1):

A not so elegant but fast solution would be

```
    const data = {
      "root": {
           "title": "Shapes",
           "shapes": { a: 'name' },
           "description": "All sorts of geometrical whizz"
      }
  };

  const object = {};

  Object.values(data.root).forEach((a, i) => {
    // console.log(a);
    if (typeof(a) === 'object') {
      object[Object.keys(data.root)[i]] = a;
    }
  });

  Object.values(data.root).forEach((a, i) => {
    // console.log(a);
    if (!(typeof(a) === 'object')) {
      object[Object.keys(data.root)[i]] = a;
    }
  });
  console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter answer

```
let data = {
  "root": {
    "title": "Shapes",
    "shapes": { key: 'value' },
    "description": "All sorts of geometrical whizz"
  }
};

/*
 * looping through your `root` object's keys
 * if the value of the key is object then assign the whole `data.root` object to a new object which starts with
 * that key-value pair
 */
Object.keys(data.root).map(key => {
  if ((typeof data.root[key]) === "object")
    data.root = Object.assign({ [key]: data.root[key] }, data.root);
});
```